# Sample size effects comparision of correlations

Tags: correlation

I have 2 datasets `data1` and `data2` (these are 2 different canals on television) that each contains `promotion` and `new_users`. So `head(data1)` gives

```
promotion    new_users
22                  23
4                    6
...
```

The same goes for `data2`. Now we notice that `dim(data1) = 3119 2` and `dim(data2) = 25488 2` so we have much more data on the **second** canal because we simply had more promotion-insertions on it.

I want to test if `new_users` correlate with `promotion` for `data1` and `data2`. In R I have done this:

```
cor.test(data1$promotion, data1$new_users, alternative="greater",method="pearson")
```

and similar for the second dataset

```
cor.test(data2$promotion, data2$new_users, alternative="greater",method="pearson")
```

which both gives very low p-values which means that we have a positive correlation for both canals.

I want to compare the 2 correlations (the correlation for the first canal `data1` and the second canal `data2`). I do this in R using Fisher's Correlation-test, where I get a p-value higher than 0.05 meaning that the positive correlation in canal 2 is significantly higher than the positive correlation in canal 1.

Is this a valid conclusion when the size of the two datasets is so different? `data1` don't contains so much data as `data2` - or does the size of the datasets even matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the formula for comparing two correlations using Fisher's hyperbolic arc tangent transformation you will see that it involves something like

Defining $z_i$ as $\tanh^{-1}{r_i}$ and $n_i$ as sample size for $i=1,2$

$$
   sdz = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1 - 3} + \frac{1}{(n_2 - 3)}}
$$
and
$$
   z = \frac{z_1 - z_2}{sdz}
$$

So you can see that the sample size has already been incorporated into the calculations.

Comment: So this means that the sample size don't have any effect on my conclusion in my case?

Comment: Not as far as I can see.